# After profiling an XCUI test in XCode, how do I see the results?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, instruments, xcuitest

I have a set of XCUI tests that are over-engineered, poorly written and are taking unnecessarily long to run. I'm using the [OSSignposter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/os/ossignposter) API to determine what bits of our emergent test framework code are slowing us down the most.

I'll run a test by right-clicking it and choosing "Profile fooTest()". How do I view the results after it completes?

Answer (score 1):

If you think the test code is poorly written then xcresult file can be helpful for you to find the problem. It contains details of every action and time takes to execute.